# Initial data for Django Admin inline formset is not saved

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to pre-fill some inlines in Django Admin with data passed as query params (in case of adding a new object in DB).

```
class TestCaseInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    class Meta:
        model = TestCase
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestCaseInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        ids_string = self.request.GET.get('ids')
        if ids_string:
            ids = [int(x) for x in ids_string.split(',')]
            self.initial = [{'test_case': id} for id in ids]


class TestCaseInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TestCase
    raw_id_fields = ('test_case',)
    extra = 1
    formset = TestCaseInlineFormSet

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        formset = super(TestCaseInline, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        formset.request = request
        return formset

    def get_extra(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        extra = super(TestCaseInline, self).get_extra(request, obj, **kwargs)
        requested_extras = len(request.GET.get('ids', '').split(','))
        return max(extra, requested_extras)
```

The data is pre-filled fine with this solution, however there's an issue when trying to submit: the pre-filled inlines are not marked as changed, so they're not saved.

I've tried overriding has_changed() on the TestCaseInlineFormSet however it doesn't solve the problem - it seems has_changed() for the formset is never called?

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I think you couldn't use `__init__` cause it works every time you hit admin. you can use `prepopulated_fields`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields

Comment: Hi, Seuling, can you provide sample? I cannot figure it out how to populate multiple records as initial data in tabluarinline.